# How to retrieve the C++ class name via member function in llvm?

Tags: c++, llvm

Given the C++ member function, I wonder if there's any approach to retrieve the llvm::StructType * in IR level.

Example could be:

```cpp
#define CIRCLE 1
class Circle {
    int getType() {return CIRCLE;}
}
```

I would like to get the pointer of the %class.Circle using the llvm::Function * of getType().

Comment: Generally possible, I'd say, but it depends on what you have and what you're allowed to use, so as it stands, the question is too unclear to answer. Calling getType() is easy if you have a Value, less so if you don't. If you're allowed to make assumptions about the type naming in use, finding structs by name is easy. And so on.